# How to test that Java class is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Let's take this simple class:

```
public class CounterService {

    private volatile Counter counter;

    public  CounterService(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public  long getCounterValue() {
        System.out.println("GET: " + this.counter.counter + " in thread " +
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return this.counter.counter;
    }

    public  long setCounterValue(long newValue) {
        this.counter = this.counter.updateCounter(newValue);
        System.out.println("--set: " + newValue + " in thread " +
                Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return this.counter.counter;
    }
}


public class Counter {

    public final long counter;

    public Counter(long counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public Counter updateCounter(long i) {
        return new Counter(i);
    }
}
```

Now I want to write the unit test, that will **always** pass, if the `CounterService` is thread safe (eg. when I set `get` and `set` methods synchronized). I belive that writing a test, which will always fail if this class isn't thread safe, may be impossible.

I tried with something like this:

```
@Test
public void multipleThreadSetAndGetShouldCorrectValue() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    int threads = 10;
    final Counter counter = new Counter(0);
    final CounterService counterService = new CounterService(counter);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    Collection<Future<Long>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicLong sequence = new AtomicLong(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        results.add(executorService.submit(() -> {
            latch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            latch.countDown();
            counterService.setCounterValue(sequence.getAndIncrement());
            return counterService.getCounterValue();
        }));
    }

    final Set<Long> uniqueResult = new HashSet<>();
    for (Future<Long> result : results) {
        uniqueResult.add(result.get());

    }

    assertEquals(threads, uniqueResult.size());
}
```

But this test will occasionally fail even if the `CounterService` is thread safe.

How to write unit test that will always pass when the class is thread safe? How to write test to check, that `get` method returns the last set value, even if it was modified by another thread?

Comment: "But this test will occasionally fail even if the CounterService is thread safe." That somewhat implies that it's not thread-safe. For example, `this.counter = this.counter.updateCounter(newValue);` and `return this.counter.counter;` are not executed atomically, so `this.counter` might not be the same in both statements.

Comment: There  might be frameworks for the purpose, you may try searching. Otherwise just run a number of threads each testing the functionality of the class. This will never issue a guarantee that it *is*  thread-safe (no test can ever do that), but if the test fails, it might indicate that it isn’t.

Comment: @AndyTurner if I set `synchronized` to `set` and `get` methods, the CounterService will be thread safe, but even so, my test occasionally fails.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `Counter` class is pointless. The `updateCounter` method doesn't update, it returns a new object. So just delete the `Counter` class and use `long` in your `CounterService`.

There then remains the question as to what `CounterService` is for. It just wraps a long.

But disregarding that. No - you can't really write a test to prove that something is not thread-safe as multi-threading problems are not deterministic. You could insert delays into places where you know race conditions might occur, but that only works if you already know it isn't thread-safe in a particular place and you want to prove it. But if you don't know where the problem is you might not be able to insert the delays in the right place to prove the possible problem does exist.

By the same token, you can't really prove that it is correct either, although again you can increase your chances by inserting sleeps between operations to force problems. But it may not work and you are not testing the real-world scenario.

Your test is failing because you don't understand what synchronized does and what thread-safely implies.

In your test, you are setting a counter value and then getting it in the next line. If you synchronize the set and the get, all that means is that the individual get and set operations are thread-safe. It doesn't mean that you can call get and set separately and that get will return the same value that the previous set used.

If you want to set something and then get the same value back again safely you have to wrap the get and the set calls in a synchronized block.

```
synchonized(this) { // get must return same thing that was set
    set
    get
}
```

I strongly recommend that you focus on understanding what your program needs to achieve and what thread-safety and sychronization means in that context. Otherwise, you won't be able to develop a correct test anyway.

Comment: Well my code above is really simplified. The `Counter` class is just simple example of the immutable object. My `CounterService` will be used as service in Spring Webflux project and I want to be sure that every get request will returns the last set value. I just didn't know that write the code to test it is so difficult (or even impossible).

Comment: If you want a get to return the last set you have to synchronize as I showed above. But this is a contrived example, as there is no point in calling get. You can just check the return value of set. In general, ensuring that get returns the last value of set over an arbitrary timespan requires a single-threaded application.